# SharePoint GUID version changed without installing sharepoint CU's

Tags: patching

I am having SharePoint Server 2013 and Patching team did install SharePoint 2013 Security/Windows/OS Patches and it did changed the Configuration database version from August 2015(prior to patch) to July 2016( after OS and Security Patches).SharePoint Team didn't even install any SharePoint CU's but the DB versions have been upgraded in Central Admin.

I am sure that doesn't mean the July 2016 CU is installed? Correct ?. I still would have to install the CU's separately and I was planning to do the May 2016 CU(unless anybody recommends June or July or August 2016) as I would like to stay couple of CU's behind Microsoft. Any recommendations?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. Security patches and other hotfixes can certainly update the Farm Build #, but it does not mean the corresponding Cumulative Update is installed.

In order to identify which component has been updated, in Central Administration, under Upgrade and Migration, Check product or patch installation status. This will list each individual product and provide the build number.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response. Is looking at Manage Patch Status the only way to find out which patch is installed and its lot so not really sure which one I am looking for. So this Configuration database version:15.0.4841.1000 doesn't mean anything? in CA

Comment: I think people conflate the farm build # with 'cumulative update' (or Service Pack). It has never specifically meant that -- all it has ever meant was that a patch was installed that updated the configuration database schema. The other place you can check is 'Windows Update -> View Installed Updates' (or under Programs and Features) to see specifically which patches have been applied.